# REST POST MIME on client (actionscript) when trying to POST to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: actionscript-3, rest, post, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to do a POST to insert values in a Sharepoint 2013 list from an AIR client.
The GET works and authentication is ok.

Here is my as3 code:

```
URLRequestDefaults.authenticate = true;
URLRequestDefaults.setLoginCredentialsForHost("srv", "usr", "pwd");

var postURL:URLRequest= new URLRequest("http://srv/site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('list')/items");      
postURL.authenticate = true;
postURL.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
postURL.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader("ACCEPT","application/json;odata=verbose"));
postURL.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader("ContentType","application/json"));
postURL.data = JSON.stringify({ '_metadata': { 'type': 'SP.listnameListItem' }, 'Title': 'desc' });
postLoader = new URLLoader(postURL);
postLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
postLoader.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, postDone);
postLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleIOError );
postLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, handleHttpStatus );
postLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handleSecurityError );
postLoader.load(postURL);
```

When I run it, it goes to the handleIOError method:

```
private function handleIOError ( event:IOErrorEvent ):void
{
 trace ( "Load failed: IO error: " + event.text );
 trace ( "data IO error: " + event.currentTarget.data.toString() );
}
```

I got this error: Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataContentTypeException A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type 
    of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/atom+xml;type=feed,
    application/atom+xml, application/json;odata=verbose' matches the content type
   'text/xml;charset=utf-8'
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found out adding/modifying these line made it work:

```
postURL.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader("ContentType","application/json;odata=verbose"));
postURL.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader("X-RequestDigest",FormDigestValue ));
postURL.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader("If-Match","*"));
postURL.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader("X-Http-Method","POST"));
postURL.contentType="application/json;odata=verbose";
```